# Bootstrap font size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-size

Is it possible to change all original Bootstrap font sizes of h1,h2,h3,h4 etc. elements at the same time by adding something to custom css file without writing new sizes for each separate element.

My idea is to make font sizes smaller:

```
    h1,
    h2,
    h3,
    h4,
    h5,
    h6 
    {
   80% of Bootstrap font sizes;
    }
```

Comment: i dont think so , but you can override like so : h1{font-size:40px !important}

Answer (score 1):

you can change the styling in bootstrap.min.css but its not a good practice rather than you should make the changes into your css only ,the best ways give your wrapper name followed by H1

```
 eg: wrappnername h1,h2,h2,h4{font-size:12px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'em' to set a relative 
font-size

```
 h1, h2, h3, h4{ font-size: 0.8em; }
```

If that does not make a differance try adding the !important